# Division of Array into parts based upon a 2nd Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Two arrays one with objects and other with string values, based on second arrays values looking to dive first one to multiple. In my case it is two.

```
    let arr1=  [{"key": "English","code": "en"}, {"key": "Arabic","code": "ar"},
            {"key": "Chinese (traditional)","code": "zh"},
    {"key": "Czech", "code": "cs"},
            {"key": "Dutch","code": "nl"},{"key": "Finnish","code": "fi"}]

let arr2 = ["English", "Dutch", "Finnish"];

let completed =[];
let optional =[];

 for (let i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
                for (let j = 0; j < arr1.length; j++) {
                    if (arr1[j].key === arr1[i]) {
                        completed.push(arr1[j])
                    }else{
                      optional.push(arr1[j])
                    }
                }
            }
```

Aiming for output like this

```
completed=[{"key": "English","code": "en"},{"key": "Dutch","code": "nl"},
          {"key": "Finnish","code": "fi"}]

optional=[{"key": "Arabic","code": "ar"},{"key": "Chinese (traditional)","code": "zh"},
        {"key": "Czech", "code": "cs"} ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the problems with your code are:

1. Comparing the same array elements `if (arr1[j].key === arr1[i])`.
2. Not breaking the loop on finding a matching element and inserting next element immediately into `optional` array.

Fixing these issues, your code would look like:

```js
let arr1 = [{ "key": "English", "code": "en" }, { "key": "Arabic", "code": "ar" }, { "key": "Chinese (traditional)", "code": "zh" }, { "key": "Czech", "code": "cs" }, { "key": "Dutch", "code": "nl" }, { "key": "Finnish", "code": "fi" } ] ;
let arr2 = ["English", "Dutch", "Finnish"];

let completed = [];
let optional = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  let found = false;
  for (let j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
    if (arr1[i].key === arr2[j]) {
      completed.push(arr1[i]);
      found = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!found) {
    optional.push(arr1[i]);
  }
}

console.log("Completed: ", completed);
console.log("Optional: ", optional);
```

Another easier approach is to use [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```js
let arr1 = [{ "key": "English", "code": "en" }, { "key": "Arabic", "code": "ar" }, { "key": "Chinese (traditional)", "code": "zh" }, { "key": "Czech", "code": "cs" }, { "key": "Dutch", "code": "nl" }, { "key": "Finnish", "code": "fi" } ] ;
let arr2 = ["English", "Dutch", "Finnish"];

let completed = arr1.filter(item => arr2.includes(item.key));
let optional = arr1.filter(item => !arr2.includes(item.key));

console.log("Completed: ", completed);
console.log("Optional: ", optional);
```

Comment: Second solution worked like a gem. First one I tried modifying but in my application it is rendering before the result of this nested for loops. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome @srikanth. I'm glad it helped. If everything was right, first solution should work as well. There isn't a significant difference in execution time between both these solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr1=  [{"key": "English","code": "en"}, {"key": "Arabic","code": "ar"},
    {"key": "Chinese (traditional)","code": "zh"},
    {"key": "Czech", "code": "cs"},
    {"key": "Dutch","code": "nl"},{"key": "Finnish","code": "fi"}];

let arr2 = ["English", "Dutch", "Finnish"];

let completed =[];
let optional =[];

for (let j = 0; j < arr1.length; j++) {
    let isCompleted = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
        if (arr1[j].key === arr2[i]) {
            completed.push(arr1[j]);
            isCompleted = true;
        }
    }
    if (!isCompleted) {
        optional.push(arr1[j])
    }
}

console.log("Completed: ", completed);
console.log("Optional: ", optional);
```